# Are all the built in functions of a programming language made up of the primitives?

Tags: programming-languages

I know, I can define new **functions** with the help of the **primitives** that the language provides me, but I want to know if the **built-in** functions are also defined by the same primitives or there is something else that powers these functions?

Answer (score 1):

Often, yes. In many cases, the libraries provided are implementations of the language's given primitives, and someone has made various functions out of them to make your life easier.